# windows 10 python serial module not found, but pip install pyserial passed

Tags: python, windows, pyserial

```
C:\Users\antvai01\Linux\host\tests>python -m pip install pyserial
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users\antvai01\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (3.5)

C:\Users\antvai01\Linux\host\tests>sp_controller.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antvai01\Linux\host\tests\sp_controller.py", line 7, in <module>
    import get_sw_version
  File "C:\Users\antvai01\Linux\host\tests\get_sw_version.py", line 3, in <module>
    from MHUBridge import *
  File "C:\Users\antvai01\Linux\host\tests\MHUBridge\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Svalinn_MHU_Bridge import *
  File "C:\Users\antvai01\Linux\host\tests\MHUBridge\Svalinn_MHU_Bridge.py", line 5, in <module>
    import serial
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'
```

i even installed pyserial manually from source, and still the same issue. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's installing to a non-default location:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users\antvai01\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (3.5)
```

This location is probably not in your `PYTHONPATH`.

I'd be looking to see why your normal site-packages folder is not writeable

Comment: i ran it in an admin window and didnt get the warning, still have the same error